# Is 'had' in 'They had to be happy' used as a verb or adjective?

Tags: past-participles

Is 'had' in 'They had to be happy' used as a verb or adjective?

I think that "to be" is a linking verb, and 'happy' its subject complement.

But can had - meaning found it necessary - be the past participle?

Comment: If it is an adjective, which noun or pronoun is it modifying? Or is it a subject complement?

Comment: indefinite pronoun they? @Cascabel

Comment: "have to" is often classified as a modal verb, but in this case (and most) it is a main verb.

Comment: so i can use a main verb followed by a linking verb @Cascabel ?

Comment: It's a construction.. It is similar to other verb constructions that have 2 verbs, such as _like_ to be, _want_ to be, etc.

Comment: so that's a "yes" then? sorry, just seems enigmatic.

Comment: That's a "yes". See [Verbs followed by 'to' infinitive](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-by-the-infinitive)

Comment: Note that we often classify idiomatic constructions like this according to whether the first verb takes a "to" infinitive, "bare" infinitive, or "ing" form in the second verb...it's a broad, but very interesting topic.

Comment: "Had" is a verb as predicator of the verb phrase "had to be happy". It's a catenative verb, with the infinitival clause "to be happy" as its catenative complement. "Happy" is then subjective predicative complement of "be".

Comment: It doesn't mean "found it necessary" here, because it's past. It has to mean "probably"

Answer (score 1):

*Have to, has to, had to, having to*, followed by an infinitive verb phrase, is an idiom. A verbal idiom -- it's a verb, to answer the question. A **Modal** verbal idiom. This idiom comes with its own special weird pronunciation rules (*has to* is /'hæ**st**u/ -- never /z/, *have to* is /'hæ**ft**u/ -- never /v/), and its own weird grammar and meanings, like all modals.

It means the same as the modal auxiliary verb *must*, in both its **Deontic** (social, obligation) and its **Epistemic** (logical, conclusion) senses.  (all modals have both kinds of meaning; it's a modal complication)

- *She **must** be home by midnight. = She **has to** be home by midnight.* (Deontic)
- *This **must** be the right place. = This **has to** be the right place.* (Epistemic)

So, the example sentence

- *They had to be happy*

is an epistemic use of the idiom (a periphrastic modal construction, to give it its full name), since *They* can't have an obligation to be happy in the past. Indeed, one can't have any obligation to be happy, even in the present; emotions are not subject to deontic modality. One can only be obliged to do the things one is capable of doing. And no one can be obliged to change the past.

The sentence means, then, that someone (perhaps the speaker) has concluded  (from some unstated evidence) that *They* were happy, at the past time cited. It means the same thing as (but doesn't have the same structure as)

- *They must have been happy.*

That's also an epistemic conclusion, and also uses an auxiliary *have*, but it's not the same as *have to*. For one thing, the *have* in *must have* is pronounced /v/, not /f/. For another, *must have* is followed by a participle, not a *to*-infinitive. So it's different. It has to be, because *had to* is past tense, and *must* lacks a past tense. You can't say

- **They musted be happy*

But you **can** say *They had to be happy*, meaning the same thing. The reason why there are periphrastic modal constructions like *have to, ought to, be able to, be willing to,* and the rest is that they have tensed forms and infinitives and participles like real verbs, but modals are all stripped down to bare metal and don't have any of the fixings needed for that. So we have both kinds and if one doesn't serve, we use the other. Language is like that.